# Access static method from non static class possible in java and not in c#

Tags: c#, static, static-methods, static-classes

Access static method from non static class with object.
It is not possible in C#. Where it is done by JAVA.
How it works?

example of java

```
/**
* Access static member of the class through object.
*/
import java.io.*;

class StaticMemberClass {
    // Declare a static method.
    public static void staticDisplay() {
        System.out.println("This is static method.");
    }
    // Declare a non static method.
    public void nonStaticDisplay() {
        System.out.println("This is non static method.");
    }
}

class StaticAccessByObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // call a static member only by class name.
        StaticMemberClass.staticDisplay();
        // Create object of StaticMemberClass class.
        StaticMemberClass obj = new StaticMemberClass();
        // call a static member only by object.
        obj.staticDisplay();
        // accessing non static method through object.
        obj.nonStaticDisplay();
    }
}
```

Output of the program:

```
This is static method.
This is static method.
This is non static method.
```

**How to do this in C#?**
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# forbids referencing a static method through `instance.Method`, only `Type.Method` is acceptable. To call a static method, you need to go through the type, not an instance.
In your case this means that `StaticMemberClass.staticDisplay()` works, but `obj.staticDisplay()` does not.

---

> When a method is referenced in a *member-access* (§7.6.4) of the form `E.M`, if `M` is a static method, **`E` must denote a type** containing `M`, and if `M` is an instance method, `E` must denote an instance of a type containing `M`.

*(C# Language Specification Version 4.0 - 10.6.2 Static and instance methods)*

> When a static member `M` is referenced in a *member-access* (§7.6.4) of the form `E.M`, `E` must denote a type containing `M`. **It is a compile-time error for `E` to denote an instance.**

*(C# Language Specification Version 4.0 - 10.3.7 Static and instance members)*

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You'll need to use the actual class, in your case

```
StaticMemberClass.staticDisplay();
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean accessing static method with object is possible in java. But, not in c#. why this difference ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance member to wrap the call to the static member. Or make the static member an instance member.